# Difficulty creating ROC curve using library(ROCR) in R

Tags: r

I have a simple 2 column data frame the labels (binary) are `Benign` and `Malignant` and predictor is a five-point ordinal variable here is the summary

```
 data.frame':   127 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ GRADE        : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "benign"<"likely benign"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ BENIGN.MALIGN: Factor w/ 2 levels "Benign","Malignant": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

But when I use:

```
pred<-prediction(myTable[[1]],myTable[[2]])
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in prediction(myTable[[1]], myTable[[2]]) : 
Format of predictions is invalid.
```

What can i do to rectify this? Thanks

Comment: How does a 5 point system predict a dichotomous outcome?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the grade as a score and have verified or assumed that the intervals in the score are equidistant, you can convert the 5 point likert into a numeric form as follows:

`pred <- prediction(as.numeric(myTable[[1]]), myTable[[2]])`